# insert old data on another table before deleting in mysql using php at the same time by id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

let I have two tables with some data & when ever i delete data from table, I want my deleted data to insert in my back_up table using insert query by id.will you help me guys ....saying me the working query.

Comment: Instead of saving the duplicate data in second table you can use a field like status for storing the information (0- disabled 1 -active 2 -archive)

Comment: can u send me the query

Comment: the data is on 5 tables & when i delete it,,it can be inserted to my back_up table before deleting.

Answer (score -2):

when click on delete : get id ->go to db ->fetch entry using id-> add it in back_up table-> then execute delete query on on previous table...

Comment: Dont just downvote randomly without knowing who have done that.